# Postgis install - configure does not recognize GEOS version

Tags: postgis, geos

I am installing PostGIS on Ubuntu 13.04.  I have installed GEOS 3.3.8.  I have downloaded and opened postgis, and when I do ./configure it says that I need a GEOS >=3.1. Which I thought I had.  I am running configure with --with-geos-config=/home/geos-3.3.8/(etc), pointing to the version of geos I just installed. 
Why is it not finding the version I have?

Comment: looking at the log from the config command, I get ./configure: line 16640: /home/nigel/geos-3.3.8/tools/geos-config: Permssion denied.  I am following the postgis installation notes from Geodjango, should I be using sudo (installation notes only have sudo for make install step).

Answer (score 0):

To build/install PostGIS 2.1 on Ubuntu 13.04, [try following these steps](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21Ubuntu1304src).

To build/install PostGIS 2.0, [here are some similar steps](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1304src). Note that for this version of PostGIS, [packaged GEOS 3.3.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libgeos-dev) from the main repo is [sufficient](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS).

Answer (score 0):

While installing GEOS prerequisites for postGIS extension

please try **make clean** before executing **make** command

Check your geos version **geos-config --version**

hope it helps you.